# Organizing large Web API solution

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Good day,

I will begin developing a Web API solution for a multi-company organization. I'm hoping to make available all useful data to any company across the organization.

Given that I expect there to be a lot of growth with this solution, I want to ensure that it's organized properly from the start.

I want to organize various services by company, and then again by application or function.

So, with regards to the URL, should I target a structure like:

/company1/application1/serviceOperation1

or is there some way to leverage namespaces:

/company2.billing/serviceOperation2

Is it possible to create a separate Web API project in my solution for each company? Is there any value in doing so?

Hope we're not getting too subjective, but the examples I have seen have a smaller scope, and I really see my solution eventually exposing a lot of Web API services.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: If the data coming out of the API(s) can be useful for many companies in the organisation, do you need to divide them up by company? Is the data coming back company agnostic?

Comment: For instance, I could expose the geolocation coordinates of our transport trucks, which could be used by the other companies for figuring out shipping logistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before writing a line of code I would be looking at how the information is to be secured and deployed, versioned and culture of the company.

Will the same security mechanisms (protocols, certificates, modes, etc.) be shared across all companies and divisions?

`If they are shared then there is a case for keeping them in the same solution`

Will the services cause differing amounts of load and be deployed onto multiple servers with different patching schedules?

`If the services are going onto different servers then they should probably be split to match`

Will the deployment and subsequent versioning schedule be independent for each service or are all services always deployed together?

`If they are versioned independently then you would probably split the solution accordingly`

How often does the company restructure and keep their applications?

`If the company is constantly restructuring without you would probably want to split the services by application. If the company is somewhat stable and focused on changing the application capabilities then you would probably want to split the services by division function (accounts, legal, human resources, etc.)`

As for the URL to access this should naturally flow from the answers above. Hope this helps.